# Static, Singleton or instance?

Tags: java

I'm a bit confused about my new class type I've written.
My class would be used to serve question and options pulled from database for about four thousands concurrent users. (Because exam will start at the same time for all)
Now what class type should I use for making it work faster.

Would it be good if I make it static?

```
public static List<Questions> getQuestions(String qType){
   List<Questions> objListExamsExt = new ArrayList<Questions>();
            ....
            ....
            ....      
        while (cursor.next()) {
            Questions objExamQuestion = new Questions();
            objExamQuestion.setQuestion_id(cursor.getString("question_id"));
            ....
            ....
            ....
            objListExamsExt.add(objExamQuestion);
        }
    return objListExamsExt;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to have different configurations or you'll always use the same database?

Comment: Singleton is the slowest one btw

Comment: @Bálint Please don't joke. People may think you're serious and think that there's a speed difference instead of a design difference.

Comment: It doesnt matter, however, the code does not throw any light on your design. If you are getting all questions in one go, static or singleton doesn't matter, code will execute once and give same performance. If its a one time question list, I am sure you will create only one instance of this object and you should be fine. /how 4000 threads plan to pull questions to them is where you need to focus.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm not joking. Just because of the fact that you need to use a function to retrieve an instance of the singleton class, it will be slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A case where a static class might be a good idea is when you want to collect `related pieces of functionality`, but you don't need to have any internal state in any object.

Normally you can create a static Utils class containing a whole bunch of related functions that are accessed outside the context of any specific object instance

**A singleton allows a class for which there is just one, persistent instance across the lifetime of an application**.A singleton class might be useful if you have some kind of shared resource, such as a database, an in-memory cache, or maybe some specialized piece of hardware like a robotic arm. Many parts of your program might want to use this resource and you might want to have all access to the resource go through a single point. A singleton isn't always the only way to handle these situations, but it's one of the few places I think a singleton might be a good choice.

**In your case** if `getQuestions()` is used in multiple places in your application then you can group it together inside a static Utils Class.